# Autolayout issue on iPhone 4S running iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout

I've been testing one of my apps in all iOS devices that I have access to. The autolayout constraints that I added using storyboard works fine in all of them but in a iPhone 4S which is running iOS 8.3. I made the same test in another iPhone 4S running iOS 7 and works fine as well.

Does anyone have any idea what may be going? Is there any bug related to auto-layout on iOS 8 for iPhone 4S?

I appreciate any help!

Comment: please add more info to your problem. Which constraints do you use? Can you add maybe some screenshot? I think we all need more info for help you :)

Comment: I'm new here, I don't have reputation enough to post a screenshot.. :(

But the view has 2 UIImageView and a UIButton. The UIButton is placed in the bottom of the view. For this UIButton, I added the following constraint:  
- Vertical Space - Bottom Layout Guide - button
This constraint has the highest priority of the view. I also add other constraint to the button but with lower priority: 
Vertical Space - (≥) - button - imageView
Thanks!

Comment: You should edit your question to include a description of all your constraints, and what the problem is on an iPhone 4s. Saying it doesn't work isn't useful in diagnosing your problem.

Answer (score 0):

uhm I try to help you.

So the only "problem" that I had already encountered with Autolayout and iOS 7 is relative to the **constraints to margins**. This feature is developed for iOS 8 and in some case I had some UI problems with iOS 7, but I'm not sure that is your problem: check eventually if you use this feature and set constraints not to margins.

I read the contraints that you use, it's hard to understand really your situation but first of all, do you really need the set some priority for few constraints?

..and please, add comment or edit your question with more info: we need to understand what is the real problem; in iOS 8.3 with iPhone 4S what's happen to your layout? :)